# Activating specific email in Outlook with VBA & deleting signature from the copied text

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm looking to use the `get` function in vba in order to activate a specific email in Outlook and then copy the body into a new email and send. I can use the `getlast` function to get the latest email in the inbox, however I would like to refine the code some more by selecting the latest email from a specific email address.

Also, I'd love how to know how to delete the signature from the text pasted into the new email.

```
Sub Negotiations()

Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim BodyText As Object
Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector

Set myItem = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.GetLast
myItem.Display

'copy body of current item

Set activeMailMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
activeMailMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy

' Create the message.
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'paste body into new email
Set BodyText = objMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range
BodyText.Paste

'set up and send notification email
With objMsg
    .To = "@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Negotiations"
    .HTMLBody = activeMailMessage.HTMLBody
    .Display

End With
End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Open the Inbox folder using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox), retrieve the Items collection from MAPIFolder.Items. Sort the items (Items.Sort) on the ReceivedTime property, retrieve the latest email using Items.Find on the SenderEmailAddress property.

Comment: How does this code work exactly, sorry I've just tried to use the SenderEmailAddress property but it also reports that object is empty!

Comment: The code is above, in totality. There is an option in the rule section of Outlook which allows you to run a code once a condition is met. Thus, presently, when I receive an email from a particular address, it triggers this script which access the latest email in the inbox. I'd just like to specify the code to get an email from a defined email address, instead of just taking the last, as this will lead to errors... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggested to use GetDefaultFolder/Items.Sort/Items.Find. What is your code that does that?

Comment: Here is my script so far:

Comment: So does it not display the most recent message? What is the current problem?

Comment: It's weird, when I do tries just running the code in VBA manually, under different conditions, it works perfectly, but when I set a rule and tell Outlook to run a script it does not work, it appears to not allow the email to be accessed or something. It always takes the second last email. I wonder if I wrote in some code to display the email would that help, still, I cannot even access the email - I'm confused.

Comment: Your code assumes that there is an open message - ActiveInspector.CurrentItem. Do you not want to use the latest message returned by myItems.GetLast?

Comment: Yeah, I need to copy the content of a email. Therefore, when I receive an email from a particular address, I set a rule to move this email into a folder, then I run the script. The script should access the folder, mark all items as read, sort by date, get last, copy email, paste into new email, search email for particular string, delete everything after that string, then replace the email string with nothing and send. It does everything but the getlast function takes second last email, not the one I want!!!

Answer (score 0):

Dependant on what your property of `.SenderEmailAddress` returns, you can adapt what the while statement evaluates for. This should work for you, by first looking at the last e-mail, and then checking each previous e-mail for the correct sender address.

```
Sub display_mail()
    Dim outApp As Object, objOutlook As Object, objFolder As Object
    Dim myItems As Object, myItem As Object
    Dim strSenderName As String

    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlook = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    strSenderName = UCase(InputBox("Enter the e-mail Alias."))

    Set myItem = myItems.GetLast
    While Right(myItem.SenderEmailAddress, Len(strSenderName)) <> strSenderName
        Set myItem = myItems.GetPrevious
    Wend
    myItem.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi this is some super nice code, the main issue, and perhaps something I neglected to mention, is that I set-up a rule so that the script would run when an email from a particular email address is received. Thus the process really needs to be automated, therefore, having an InputBox is far from ideal.

Comment: If you intend for the code to only impact 1 e-mail recipient, then you can just assign a constant value to the strSenderName variable (although it would make sense to then make it a Const instead of a variable).

Answer (score 0):

> Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.GetLast
>   activeMailMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy

First of all, I'd recommend breaking the chain of calls. Declare each property or method call on a separate line of code, so you will be able to debug the code at any time and see what happens under the hood.

The [GetLast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869214(v=office.15).aspx) method returns the last object in the collectio. But it doesn't mean that the item is recieved last. You need to sort the collection using the [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960(v=office.15).aspx) method as Dmitry suggested passing the ReceivedTime property as a parameter to sort on. Only in that case you will get the last recieved item from the collection.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any special method or property for identifying signatures. You need to parse the message body and find it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, and to everyone, this is really insightful stuff and I am just  trying to wrap my head around it all!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Nego()

Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim BodyText As Object
Dim Inspector As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim msgStr As String
Dim endStr As String
Dim endStrStart As Long
Dim endStrLen As Long
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items



    'Access folder Nego
Const olFolderInbox = 6
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    strFolderName = objInbox.Parent
    Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName)
    Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Nego")

    'Mark as read
For Each objMessage In objFolder.Items
    objMessage.UnRead = False
    Next

    'Sort
Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    For Each myItem In myItems
    myItems.Sort "Received", False
    Next myItem
    myItems.GetLast.Display

    'copy body of current item
Set activeMailMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    activeMailMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy

    ' Create the message.
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'paste body into new email
Set BodyText = objMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range
    BodyText.Paste

    'Search Body
Set activeMailMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    endStr = "first line of signature"
    endStrLen = Len(endStr)
    msgStr = activeMailMessage.HTMLBody
    endStrStart = InStr(msgStr, endStr)
    activeMailMessage.HTMLBody = Left(msgStr, endStrStart + endStrLen)

    'set up and send email
With objMsg
    .To = "@email"
    .Subject = "Nego"
    .HTMLBody = activeMailMessage.HTMLBody
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "First line of signature", " ")
    .Send

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: The code still does not work, when I sort the emails by latest and use the getlast function, it still does not get the newest email - I thought this was because the newest email is marked as unread, I tried to create a script after a rule criterion has been met in outlook, but the mark as read function appears not to be working. Nevertheless, any advice would be appreciated!!!